# CatBoost Error: bayesian bootstrap doesn't support taken fraction option

Tags: bayesian, bootstrapping, catboost

The error occur when running gridsearchcv using catboostclassifier and bootstrap_type='Bayesian'. Any idea what that error means?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while training my data with CatBoostClassifier. I had set the "subsample" parameter to "0.5". After removing this parameter, it worked for me.
More details at: [enter link description here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1410)

Hope this is useful.